# Abstract class PHP сколько занимает оперативной памяти?

Tags: php, классы, производительность

Сколько может занять памяти абстрактный класс, допустим с 20 методами и 20 переменными? Как абстрактные классы влияют на производительность? Есть проект который должен работать даже на самом слабом бесплатном хостинге.

Comment: Класс занимает мало, неважно, абстрактный или нет, ведь класс - просто описание структуры данных. Занимают место объекты. Вы можете создать класс с одной переменной и заполнить память тысячами объектов этого класса.

Comment: сдается мне 20 методов в классе займут в таблице методов столько уже указателей, сколько и 20 глобальных функций. разве что накладные расходы появятся на наследование при перекрытии в потомках